# Problems with sending commit data on post-receive hook via curl (git)

Tags: git, curl, git-post-receive

The aim of my project is to log every commit made by a developer into mongodb. I have set up a
 nodejs listener that will persist data received on a post to mongo.

I am running a gitolite server, and every time a developer pushes I am using a post-receive hook to post the commits via curl to my node listener.

I am successfully doing this, apart from on an initial commit where the old revision is `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000` I get an invalid argument when I try and run git log.

> ambiguous argument
>   '8a2db961045bd4825624b16ad62e75be49dd70b6~1..8a2db961045bd4825624b16ad62e75be49dd70b6':
>   unknown revision or path not in the working tree. Use '--' to separate
>   paths from revisions

An excerpt from my bash/post-receive script is below.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Read git data on STDIN
while read oval nval ref ; do
    if expr "$ref" : "^refs/heads/"; then
        if expr "$oval" : '0*$' >/dev/null
        then
            revspec=$nval
        else
            revspec=$oval..$nval
        fi
        other_branches=$(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads/ |
            grep -F -v $ref)

        # Get the name of the repository
        if [ $(git rev-parse --is-bare-repository) = true ]
        then
                 REPOSITORY_BASENAME=$(basename "$PWD")
        else
                REPOSITORY_BASENAME=$(basename $(readlink -nf "$PWD"/..))
        fi
        REPOSITORY_BASENAME=${REPOSITORY_BASENAME%.git}

        for revision in `git rev-parse --not $other_branches | 
            git rev-list --stdin $revspec`; do
                COMMIT_ID=$(git log $revision~1..$revision --pretty=format:'%H')
                DATE=$(git log $revision~1..$revision --date=short --pretty=format:'%ad')
                MSG=$(git log $revision~1..$revision --pretty=format:'%s')
                AUTHOR=$(git log $revision~1..$revision --pretty=format:'%ae')
                curl -s
                    -d "commit_id=$COMMIT_ID&date=$DATE&msg=$MSG&author=$AUTHOR&project=$REPOSITORY_BASENAME"
                    $LISTENER_RECEIVE
        done
    fi
done
```

I am not exactly sure how to deal with this in my bash script/with the git commands I am using.

One (lazy) option would be to use git log with out any of the revision information, and avoid adding duplicate commits to my collection using the project name/git commit id. But that would be slow on large repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's going to help here, but in the pre-commit.sample hook, they use this trick:

```
if git rev-parse --verify HEAD >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    against=HEAD
else
    # Initial commit: diff against an empty tree object
    against=4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
fi
```

That last hash is the hash for an empty repository and is hardcoded into git.